# Problem with moving slider with arrow keys with use of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to move slider from site:
https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/horizontal_slider
with use of jQuery in Chrome devtools snippets but it does not work:

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';
script.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
script.integrity = 'sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=';
document.head.appendChild(script);

jQuery.noConflict();

var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 39;

jQuery("input[type='range']").focus();
jQuery("input[type='range']").trigger(press);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code need a bit of correction.

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';
script.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
script.integrity = 'sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=';
document.head.appendChild(script);

jQuery.noConflict();

var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 39;

// You selecting all the inputs with a type of range. this will return an array of elements so you can use a loop to iterate over all the elements or if there is a single element you use array indexing,

jQuery("input[type='range']").focus(); 
jQuery("input[type='range']").trigger(press);
```

Updated Code -:

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';
script.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
script.integrity = 'sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=';
document.head.appendChild(script);

jQuery.noConflict();

// Selecting first element from the array
let slider =  jQuery("input[type='range']")[0];
 
// Use value to move the slider left or right;
slider.value = 39;

// Execute if you wish to change the value of the Span Element as well there is a predefined function
showValue(39)
```

Comment: But why this not work with keypress event?

Comment: You need to add an event listener on the window for `keydown` event and then capture that event and using conditions you can increase the range or decrease it.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code in like

```
script.onload = function() {
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //your code goes here
  })
}
document.head.appendChild(script);
```